# regular expression for decimal with fixed total number of digits

Tags: regex, perl

Is there a way to write regular expression that will match strings like

```
(0|[1-9][0-9]*)\.[0-9]+
```

but with a specified number of numeric characters. for example: for 3 numeric characters it should match "0.12", "12.3" but not match "1.234" or "1.2". I know I can write it something like

```
(?<![0-9])(([0-9]{1}\.[0-9]{2})|([1-9][0-9]{1})\.[0-9]{1})(?![0-9])
```

but that becomes quite tedious for large number of digits.

(I know I don't need {1} but it better explains what I'm doing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
^(?=[\d.]{4}$)\d+\.\d+$
```

You can try this for `3` digits.Can be extended for more.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/bN8dL3/4

or

```
 \b(?=[\d.]{4}\b)\d+\.\d+\b
```

If you dont want `anchors`.

Answer (score 0):

You can match them with adding alternatation:

```
\b(?:[0-9]\.[0-9]{2}|[1-9][0-9]\.[0-9])\b
```

Then, you won't need any start/end string/line anchors.

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/eR4sU3/3)